# can't install ruby with rvm on windows11 wsl

Tags: rvm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

### problem

i upgraded my windows to windows 11 and have ruby on rails projects in the wsl (ubuntu 18.04 ).

i use rvm to manage my ruby versions

after running

```sh
rvm install 3.0.0
```

during install the console displays : `verify binary`
and i get windows blue screen with `STOP: MEMORY_MANAGEMENT`
before the computer restarts

### I have done

- I have run memory diagnostics tools they return no problems
- I have tried reinstalling rvm but then can't install any ruby versions
- I have tried installing other versions of ruby on the same rvm the same problem occurs
- I have tried installing rbenv and cannot install ruby either.

### my installation and machine

```sh
➜  ~ rvm -v
rvm 1.29.12 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
➜  ~ rvm list
   ruby-2.6.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.5 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.7.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-3.0.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

➜  ~ rvm use 3.0.0
Using /home/trevorius/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0
ruby: error while loading shared libraries: /home/trevorius/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/../lib/libruby.so.3.0: invalid ELF header
```

```
Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz
Ram: 16.0 GB (15.8 GB usable)
System type : 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

OS: Windows 11 Home
   version: 21H2
   wsl: Ubunto 18.04
```

#### edit

```
PS C:\Users\trevo> wsl -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-18.04    Running         1
```

Comment: First off, thanks for posting an on-topic WSL question :-).  I see a lot that are borderline or off-topic, and this one looks solid to me.  Next up, could you confirm the WSL version of the Ubuntu 18.04 instance with `wsl -l -v` (from PowerShell or CMD)?  If it was upgraded from an older Windows 10 installation, then it may be WSL1.

Comment: Third, I'm not an expert here on security vulnerabilities, but a note from the [Microsoft WSL Github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL):  *"Do not open Github issues for Windows crashes (BSODs) or security issues. Please direct all Windows crashes and security issues to secure@microsoft.com. Issues with security vulnerabilities may be edited to hide the vulnerability details."*  Since the crash that you mentioned is reproducible, at least on your system, it *may* be something that could b used to exploit a Windows issue.

Comment: yes it is wsl 1 here is what i got  see post edit. 

i will report the problem to microsoft.

Comment: thank you verry much for you help i soved my problem by upgrading wsl ( see solution )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution i used

i ended up upgrading wsl to wsl 2
using `wsl --set-version Ubuntu-18.04 2` from a powershell terminal

i had to delete the corrupted ruby files for this to work but the first run gave me the location of the files. and a couple of `rm -rf <corrupted folders>` allowed the process to complete.

Be warned this is a relatively long process took me approx 15mins per run.

after the process i was able to run the install of ruby 3.0.0 with no problem.

thank you NotTheDr01ds for putting me on track with a solution